# The internal energy change for a reversible cycle is zero?

Tags: thermodynamics

The internal energy change for a reversible "cycle" is larger than zero? (not reversible "process")
AND, internal energy change for a irreversible cycle is zero?

My book (the book is designed to prepare to pass the national qualification test in Korea—Engineer General Machinery; similar to FE Mechanical in USA. maybe) says that "reversible cycle: $dU>0$, irreversible cycle: $dU=0$"

But, I think it is incorrect.
I can't find errata of the book.

Comment: If it’s a cycle, the initial and final states are the same.  That means that $ \Delta U=0$.

Comment: Isn't that when Gibbs free energy is zero it is in equilibrium? I thought it would mean that the process nor the reverse process are spontaneous.

Comment: @Chet Miller both reversible cycle and irreversible cycle is ?

Answer (score 1):

> My book says that "reversible cycle : dU>0, irreversible cycle : dU=0"

The statement makes no sense. Cycle reversibility only impacts entropy, and only impacts total entropy of a cycle (system + surroundings).

The change in internal energy of the system for any thermodynamic cycle is always zero, regardless of whether the cycle is reversible or not. The change in total energy (internal plus external forms) of the surroundings is also zero since the work done on the surroundings by the system equals the heat transfer to the system from the reservoirs in the surroundings.

The change in entropy, $\Delta S$, of the system for any thermodynamic cycle is also zero, regardless of whether the cycle is reversible or not. That's because entropy, like internal energy is a state property. However, for an irreversible cycle there is an increase in entropy of the surroundings making the total entropy change (system plus surroundings) larger for an irreversible cycle than a reversible cycle. That's because, unlike internal energy, entropy is not a conserved quantity. Entropy is generated ("created", if you will) in an irreversible cycle.

So you can say, for a reversible cycle $\Delta S_{tot}=0$ and for an irreversible cycle $\Delta S_{tot}\gt0$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bob.  You are correct that, when the system operates in a cycle, its change in internal energy is zero.  But, when the system operates in a cycle, the change in internal energy of the surroundings is not zero.  It is negative, and equal in magnitude to the amount of work that the system does per cycle.

Comment: @ChetMiller Hmm. But isn't the net work done by the system energy transfer to the surroundings? And wouldn't that  equal the net heat transfer from the surroundings to the system?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  This net heat transfer is equal to the change in U of the reservoirs.

Comment: @ChetMiller I guess I'm dense, but doesn't the heat transfer from the reservoirs to the system equal the energy transfer from the system to the surroundings in the form of work, for a change in internal energy of the surroundings of zero?

Comment: We usually consider the working fluid as the system, and the reservoirs as part of the surroundings.  The surroundings are not doing the work.  The hot reservoir gives  up heat, and the cold reservoir receives a lesser amount of heat, so the internal energy of the reservoirs (i.e., surroundings) decreases.  If you, instead, view the reservoirs and the working fluid/engine as a larger combined system, then its internal energy decreases and it does work (but does not exchange heat with its surroundings).

Comment: @ChetMiller I am considering the working fluid as the system and the reservoirs as the surroundings. But the reservoirs are not the only thing in the surroundings. Something, somewhere in the surroundings has received energy in the form of work from the system. In the spirit of the "season", that income (work) needs to be included with the expense (heat) to "balance the books" for the surroundings.  I was trying to contrast that with entropy in my answer.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is for the benefit of @Bob D.

We have already considered the response of the surroundings to the net heat flow from the surroundings to the system $Q_{net}$; this results in a decrease in the internal energy of the surroundings/reservoirs $\Delta U_R$ :  $$\Delta U_R=-Q_{net}$$It is also important to consider the response of the surroundings to  the work W done by the system on the surroundings.  Assuming that the work done on the surroundings results in no additional heat exchange with the reservoirs, we have that $$\Delta U_O+\Delta (PE)+\Delta (KE)=W$$where $\Delta U_O$ is any additional change in internal energy of the surroundings associated with the work that the system does on the surroundings, $\Delta (PE)$ is the change in potential energy of the surroundings, and $\Delta (KE)$ is the change in kinetic energy of the surroundings.  So we have for the overall surroundings that $$\Delta U_S+\Delta (PE)+\Delta (KE)=0$$where $\Delta U_S=\Delta U_R+\Delta U_0$ is the overall change in internal energy of the surroundings.  So, if the work done by the system on the surroundings is fairly useful work, and results in raising a weight and/or accelerating a weight (such as a train, for example), the internal energy of the surroundings decreases.

Comment: So if I instead said the total change in energy (not just internal energy) of the surroundings is zero, I would be correct? In other words, considering the general equation for the first law, which includes system KE and PE as a whole, the total change in energy of the system plus surroundings is zero.

Comment: Meant which includes system and surroundings KE and PE

Comment: No, in this case, just surroundings.  The decrease in internal energy of surroundings is equal to the net useful work.

Comment: OK I think we are now on the same page. But what do you mean by useful work? And why would we limit it to useful work. Can we simply say that the energy transferred to the surroundings  equals the energy transferred to the system for a net energy change of zero for both the system and surroundings, regardless of where and what the work does on the surroundings?

Comment: We are trying to decide whether the internal energy of the. surroundings decreases or remains the same.  I contend that, under ideal conditions (i.e., all the work done by the system on the surroundings is useful work), the internal energy of the surroundings decreases.  You are contending that the internal energy of the surroundings remains constant regardless.

Comment: I have abandoned the focus on internal energy alone. I realized that I was thinking in terms of the general equation for the first law and should not have stated that the internal energy of the surroundings does not change. I have revised my answer accordingly.